# Is possible to do findViewById with "i" variable?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have 9 `ImageView` that have the same id but change only the number (image1, image2, etc...).

I want to initialize in this system:

```
mImageView = new ImageView[9];

for(int i=0; i<mImageView.length; i++)
    mImageView[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image+i);
```

Obviously this is impossible. But is there a system to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use `getIdentifier()` method from `getResources()`.

Like,

```
for(int i=0; i<mImageView.length; i++)
{
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("image"+i, 
            "id", getPackageName());
     mImageView[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
}
```

Comment: What is getPackageName()?

Comment: `getPackageName()` is method from Context class, which return your Android application package name on which, resources are categorized in R.Java file with id entries.